# Unit of work passed to methods

Tags: entity-framework, unit-of-work

I am using uow and repository pattern.

I have having trouble configuring what is the right way to perform queries in methods that are called from the main methods.

To make it clear:
I have some Method:

```
GetSomthingFromDB(int someId)
{
       using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
       {
         //Get the study from Db withrelated Entities
                IRepository<Study> studyRepository 
                =uow.GetRepository<Study();
         Foreach(var finding in study.Findings) 
         { 
            SomeSubMethod(finding);
         }
       }
}

SomeSubMethod(Finding finding)
{
  //Do all kind of stuff on a finding
}
```

OK, now in SomeSubMethod(), I need to get something from the Db, Lets say something from configuration table.

But I don't have uow inside the subMethod (could be that subMethods calls another subMethod, and Only there I need the uow again.

Should I pass uow from one Method to the other?

Should I pass the repository inner and inner?

Should I Use uow as a class member?

What is the best practice?

Thank you. Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General info:

- Keep the connection live cycle short as possbile
- if you are using WPF or ASP view then you can keep the connection (uow) alive as long the view is active.
- Desgin your methods with SRP

> Should I pass uow from one Method to the other?

Yes, some times you need to pass the unitOfWork form method to other one.

- You can pass it on private without any problem
- If you pass it to a public method you have to take care about the method scope usage to avoid any concurrency issues.

> Should I pass the repository inner and inner?

Same here repostiory belogn to a connection and, if your method is public and called from differents layers/threads, then you might get some concurrency issues.

> Should I Use uow as a class member?

Yes, and the best thing if you pass it on the constuctor as parameter and without a setter.